# Can't find /api route with api-platform

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

I'm beginner, I use Symfony / Composer / MAMP and api-platiform
I have create a new projet in the htdocs folder with the command "composer create-project"
I install api-platform with the command "composer req api"
I good have the file api_platform.yaml [api_platform.yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1WdC.png)

But i cant access to /api route on my project
I try different URL like : localhost/project/public/api, localhost/api, localhost/project/api, nothing work

Sorry for my english
Thanks to helping me

Comment: "i cant access to /api route on my project" - what does that mean? What have you tried to resolve your problem?

Comment: On all tutorial, the way is to go on : "127.0.0.1:8000/api" but this doesn't work for me

Comment: I just have 404 error

Comment: How do you access the rest of your application? Maybe you don't use port 8000 after all?

Comment: With this link : "127.0.0.1/project-name/public"

Comment: And my project is in the htdocs folder of MAMP

Comment: Then why not use `127.0.0.1/project-name/public/api`?

Comment: "The requested URL /project-name/public/api was not found on this server."

Comment: Try installing `composer require symfony/apache-pack` if you haven't already or do not have a .htaccess file in your public folder..

Comment: @user18419618, i've added an answer for future visitors, you can up it and accept it. Thanks.

Comment: How can i do that ?

Comment: @user18419618, next to my answer you can upvote with the up arrow and click the check mark to accept it.

Comment: I am missing 15 reputation points

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're missing the `.htaccess` file. When using Apache you should install the *apache-pack* with this...

`composer require symfony/apache-pack`

This will add the `.htaccess` file to your public folder for the correct rewrite rules as explained in the [docs here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html#adding-rewrite-rules).